# CSS transform center of div

Tags: html, css

I would like to make an animation in which the indicator rotates based on the center of the clock, but I still have a problem with the moving pointer during the animation. Can anyone help me?

My code:

```css
#counter-clock {
    background: url(http://bluesolution.e-kei.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/clock.png);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 154px;
    height: 154px;
    animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 rotate;
}
#counter-clock span{
        background: green;
    width: 11px;
    height: 65px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    transition: transform 1s linear;
        transform-origin: bottom center;
    transform-style: preserve-3D;
    transform: rotate(221deg);
    display: block;
    animation: test 2s  1s linear forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes test {
    0% {transform: rotate(221deg);; }
    100% { transform: rotate(380deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="vc_empty_space" id="counter-clock" style="height: 154px"><span class="vc_empty_space_inner"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute;` on the `green span` if you use `position: relative;` to it's parent element.

See comments in CSS

```css
#counter-clock {
    position: relative; /* add this line */
    
    background: url(http://bluesolution.e-kei.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/clock.png);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 154px;
    height: 154px;
    animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 rotate;
}
#counter-clock span{
        position:absolute; /* add this line */
        left:0; right:0; /* add this line */
        top:-5px; bottom:-5px; /* add this line */


        background: green;
    width: 11px;
    height: 65px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    transition: transform 1s linear;
        transform-origin: bottom center;
    transform-style: preserve-3D;
    transform: rotate(221deg);
    display: block;
    animation: test 2s  1s linear forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes test {
    0% {transform: rotate(221deg);; }
    100% { transform: rotate(380deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="vc_empty_space" id="counter-clock" style="height: 154px"><span class="vc_empty_space_inner"></span></div>
```